# npm ci crashes with local packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using nodejs 10 and npm 6.9.

I wanted to create two projects. One dependant from the other.

So I created these folders

-myapps

---parentproj

---childproj

then I did these steps:

1. go into parentproj folder
2. execute "npm create"
3. execute "npm install fs-extra" (for adding a third party reference)
4. go into childproj folder
5. execute "npm create"
6. execute "npm install ..\parentproj"

now the childproj folder contains both the package.json and package-lock.json file.

If I run "npm ci" I get this error

"npm ERR! fs-extra not accessible from parentproj"

Moreover, if I run "npm ls" from childproj folder I get this message

`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY fs-extra@^7.0.1

Am I doing something wrong?

Which is the correct way for working with local packages without publishing them?

regards.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem, but with npm `6.4.1` all is fine (`cmd` and also `bash` - I was thinking that could be a symlink problem). Could you try with that version since node 10 is bundled with that version?

Comment: I did some digging on the problem, testing with version `6.4.1` and `6.9`.
The difference I found was on the `package-lock.json` format. In the `6.4.1` version, the `parent` entry would have a dependencies field that is used by npm, while in version `6.9`, this is not present. I opened a [bug report](https://npm.community/t/npm-ci-fail-to-local-packages/6076) in the npm community, so maybe soon it will be fixed. For now, I suggest downgrading to version `6.4.1`.

Comment: I did myself some tests with older versions of npm and discovered that in the scenario described in this question, if I run command npm ci, the 6.7 version of npm works correctly. the 6.8 version breaks.

Comment: Same issue here, we've downgraded to version 6.7 too.